Need assistance to create this in LaTex Document. Am unsure how to go about it, if I should use a table or a list
This is on a Word document. I am transferring everything over to a LaTex document.
Any ideas on where to start with this? I am unsure whether to use a table or a list, and how to format it.


What is it trying to show?  Are those percentages on the right?  Why is (Low) indented more than (High)?  Are you wanting to keep the highlighted "David"?  "Table or list" might end up being off topic, although we may have some (strong) opinions (I think I vote table).  The on topic version would be how to typeset it as a table and how to typeset it as a list.

I'd probably vote for 'list' or possibly a list in a two-column table. although it really depends and it could be done either way ....

If the numbers are ar the far right of the text area, all you need is \hfill.

Or without tables nor lists:

\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabto}\NumTabs{15}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Temperature}
\tab Percent of something \hfill 120\par
\tab\tab Percent of whatever  \hfill 121\par
\tab\tab\tab Whatever  else \hfill 122\par
\subsubsection*{Materials}
\tab Percent of some more  \hfill 122
\end{document}

Suggerence: Try with \dotfill instead of \hfill.
